# How to solve proxy error in cordova latest version(3.6.3) project creation on iOS MAC?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have tried to create the cordova latest version(3.6.3) project. I'm working under the proxy environment. I have updated the proxy settings in npm. But still I'm getting the following error.
cordova create HelloPhonegap com.tyc.hello "HelloPhonegap"
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloPhonegap" and id "com.tyc.hello" at location "/Users/Desktop/HelloPhonegap"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error
    at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:159:17)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1588:9)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
How to resolve this problem? Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows XP :**

```
Open the Control Panel and click the System icon.
The System Properties dialog is displayed.
On the Advanced tab, click on Environment Variables.
The Environment Variables dialog is displayed.
Click New in the System variables panel.
The New Sytem Variable dialog is displayed.
Add http_proxy with the appropriate proxy information(http_proxy=http://proxy.example.org)
```

**Unix/MAC :**

export http_proxy xxxxxxxxxxx:xxx